# DC motor with L289N driver cannot set RPM lower than 130

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, stepper, h-bridge

My setup is using an Uno r3, and the motor driver is an L289N.

I am going to set it to run at a lower RPM, but when adjusting `enA` or `enB` to set to below 130, it won't spin.

```
// connect motor controller pins to Arduino digital pins
// motor one
int enA = 2;
int enB = 7;
int in3 = 5;
int in4 = 6;
int in1 = 3;
int in2 = 4;

void setup()
{
  // set all the motor control pins to outputs
  pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);
}
void demoOne()
{
  analogWrite(enB, 130);
  // turn on motor B
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
  delay(5000);
  // this function will run the motors in both directions at a fixed speed
  // turn on motor A
  // set speed to 200 out of possible range 0~255
  analogWrite(enA, 130);
  // turn on motor B
  digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
  // set speed to 200 out of possible range 0~255
  delay(100); //this function to set masa untuk rotation
  // now change motor directions
  // now turn off motor
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
  delay(200); 
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
  delay(5000);

  analogWrite(enB, 130);
  // turn on motor B
  digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
  delay(400);
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
  delay(5000);
}

void loop()
{
  demoOne();
  delay(3000);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are controlling two motor outputs via the H-bridge, where the logic inputs are `in1,in2` and `in3,in4`.  First of all, you need

```
pinMode(in1,OUTPUT);
pinmode(in2,OUTPUT);
```

One reason why the motors may not spin for analogWrite value less than 130 is that, coincidentally, the voltage output is too low and motor stalls.  Test this two ways: does (1) changing the motor supply voltage or (2) changing the argument of `analogWrite` actually change the speed?

If no, it may be that `pinMode(enA,OUTPUT);` sets the output as digital and should be removed.  In that case a number less than 128 gets interpreted as a logic 0 and the motor will not spin.

P.S. your code can be neatened up using port syntax and bitwise operators.

```
digitalWrite(in1,HIGH);
digitalWrite(in2,LOW);
```

can be written on a single line with

```
PORTD |= _BV(in1);
```

Also

```
digitalWrite(in1,LOW);
digitalWrite(in2,LOW);
```

becomes

```
PORTD &= ~(_BV(in1) | _BV(in2));
```

Answer (score 0):

On an Uno, `D2` and `D7` (`enA` and `enB`) do not have true PWM (analogWrite) capabilities- they will be 100% on at values of 128 or higher, and off at 127 and lower.

You will need to use 3, 5, 6, 9, 10 or 11 for PWM (i.e. your `enA` and `enB`) on the Uno.

See [Arduino Reference - analogWrite()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/) for more info on PWM pin availability on Arduino boards.